# Compiling\Building Delphi project on XE7 throws error- cannot access the file tmpXXXX.tmp.Exec.bat because it is being used

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

While compiling or building a Delphi project in XE7, most of the members in my team get below error.

> [Exec Error] The specified task executable could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\bond\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE277.tmp.Exec.bat' because it is being used by another process.

On the next run, one would get an error with a different `tmpXXXX.tmp.Exec.bat` file.

The problem here is if we try to compile build again, it might be successful.

BUT most of the time, we would have to do try this at least 5 to 6 times.

AND sometimes, the error keeps on coming no matter how many times we try.

Could someone help solve the issue?

Comment: Likely your anti virus scanner is to blame. Disable it for this folder to test that theory.

Comment: When the error happens, try using [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which process(es) are accessing the file.

Comment: Will check with ProcessExplorer if disabling Anti-Virus did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround which works 100% is to keep your CPU very busy.
I run this particular query in 3 separate threads in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @T DATETIME, @F BIGINT;
SET @T = GETDATE();
WHILE DATEADD(SECOND,120,@T)>GETDATE()
SET @F=POWER(2,30);
```

The power of 2 to 30 is a CPU heavy function and running it in 3 threads makes my CPU cross 90%. And building the Delphi project when the CPU is very busy somehow overcomes the **tmpXXX.tmp.Exec.bat is being used** issue.

I do not know why, may be the antivirus which locks the Temp folder doesn't get enough CPU. But anyway this works all the time